# How to set up AngularFire Auth with multiple providers? Material buttons for auth providers?

Tags: angularfire2

Is there a way to set up AngularFire Auth with multiple providers from a single `Login` button in the view and a single `login()` function in the component? Or do I set up separate buttons in the view and separate `loginGoogle()`, `loginFacebook()`, `loginTwitter()` etc. functions in the component for each provider?

This works:

```js
  login() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
      .then((result) => {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        console.log("Logged in!");
        console.log(result);
        this.userFullName = result.user?.displayName;
        this.userPhotoUrl = result.user?.photoURL;
        this.router.navigate(['/', 'home']);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

This doesn't work:

```js
 login() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()) // √
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider()) // √
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider()) // √
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()) // "Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app."
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider()) // "FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error)."
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider()) // "FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error)."
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.YahooAuthProvider()) // Property 'YahooAuthProvider' does not exist on type 'typeof auth'.
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.MicrosoftAuthProvider()) // Property 'MicrosoftAuthProvider' does not exist on type 'typeof auth'.
      .then((result) => {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        console.log("Logged in!");
        console.log(result);
        this.userFullName = result.user?.displayName;
        this.userPhotoUrl = result.user?.photoURL;
        this.router.navigate(['/', 'home']);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

The following should work but is a lot of code. I'm asking if there's DRYer way. The HTML would have a button for `loginGoogle()`, a button for `loginFacebook()`, a button for `loginTwitter()`, etc.

```js
loginGoogle() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
      .then((result) => {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        console.log("Logged in!");
        console.log(result);
        this.userFullName = result.user?.displayName;
        this.userPhotoUrl = result.user?.photoURL;
        this.router.navigate(['/', 'home']);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

loginFacebook() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FaceAuthProvider())
      .then((result) => {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        console.log("Logged in!");
        console.log(result);
        this.userFullName = result.user?.displayName;
        this.userPhotoUrl = result.user?.photoURL;
        this.router.navigate(['/', 'home']);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

loginTwitter() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider())
      .then((result) => {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        console.log("Logged in!");
        console.log(result);
        this.userFullName = result.user?.displayName;
        this.userPhotoUrl = result.user?.photoURL;
        this.router.navigate(['/', 'home']);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Three more questions.

1. Is there an Angular Material set of buttons for auth providers available somewhere? I made this but it doesn't look great:

[image]

2. Why are `EmailAuthProvider()` and `PhoneAuthProvider()` not working? The error message is

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).
```

3. Why are `YahooAuthProvider()` and `MicrosoftAuthProvider()` not working? The error message is:

```
Property 'YahooAuthProvider' does not exist on type 'typeof auth'.
```

Does AngularFire not support Yahoo and Microsoft?

Google, Twitter, and GitHub all worked (one at a time). My Facebook credentials appear to have something wrong, I'll look into that. Here's my Firebase Console Auth page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google provides `.png` only for web, no `.svg` https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines

Facebook provides code for `index.html` that gives you a class that calls the graphic from the Internet. I couldn't get the code to work so I took a screenshot of the Facebook button and converted it to `.png`. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/

Twitter provides a `.png`.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/guides/log-in-with-twitter

Github provides a `.png`:
https://blog.oauth.io/how-to-add-github-social-login-button/

I made a dropdown menu for the buttons. It doesn't look as good as I wanted. I'd prefer to use `.svg` files.

[image]

```html
<button mat-raised-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="loginButtons" *ngIf="!loggedIn" class="text-purple" aria-label="Login">LOGIN
    <mat-icon>login</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #loginButtons="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="loginGoogle()"><img src="../assets/signin-buttons/google-signin-buttons/web/1x/btn_google_signin_dark_normal_web.png"></button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="loginFacebook()"><img src="../assets/signin-buttons/facebook-signin-buttons/facebook_signin.png" width="187px"></button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="loginTwitter()"><img src="../assets/signin-buttons/twitter-signin-buttons/sign-in-with-twitter-gray.png.twimg.1920.png" width="187px"></button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="loginGithub()"><img src="../assets/signin-buttons/github-signin-buttons/github.png" width="187px"></button>
</mat-menu>
```

The functions in the controller were easy.

```js
loginGoogle() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
      .then((result) => {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this.userFullName = result.user?.displayName;
        this.userPhotoUrl = result.user?.photoURL;
        this.router.navigate(['/', 'home']);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  loginFacebook() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
      .then((result) => {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this.userFullName = result.user?.displayName;
        this.userPhotoUrl = result.user?.photoURL;
        this.router.navigate(['/', 'home']);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  loginTwitter() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider())
      .then((result) => {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this.userFullName = result.user?.displayName;
        this.userPhotoUrl = result.user?.photoURL;
        this.router.navigate(['/', 'home']);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  loginGithub() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider())
      .then((result) => {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this.userFullName = result.user?.displayName;
        this.userPhotoUrl = result.user?.photoURL;
        this.router.navigate(['/', 'home']);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth.signOut()
      .then((result) => {
        this.loggedIn = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/', 'landing']);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```